# Android deeplink verification: "autoVerify ignored when installing for all users"

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, intentfilter

I can tell that my deep link validation is succeeding based on seeing the following line from `adb logcat` during app install:

```
IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 0 complete. Success:true. Failed hosts:.
```

But right after that line in the logs, I see the following:

```
PackageManager: autoVerify ignored when installing for all users
```

Since autoverify seems to be ignored, when utilizing a deeplink in the emulator's testing web browser I'm prompted with the dialog box instead of an automatic redirect. I don't believe I have multiple users set up on my emulator as I used it straight out of the box. I assume that the deeplink will work on a real device since verification is successful, but wanted to test to be sure.

Looking for an explanation on why this is happening and how I can test successfully on the emulator.

Emulator: Pixel 5

API: 30

Android 11